# how to restrict user from grant statement in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I grant permission to specific users in Hive?

When I try with different users and set the permission with the GRANT statement, then these users were able to change the permission on create, update and any kind of operation on the objects(database, tables etc).
So how can I configure Hive such that only the selected user is able to grant permission?